# Jquery: animate child width by hovering parent

Tags: jquery, animation, width

I'm trying to add an animation effect to the child div's making them resize a little on hover.

I've implemented the following html:

```
<div class="nieuws_thumb_container">
  <div class="nieuws_content_left">
  </div>
  <div class="nieuws_content_right">
    <div class="pijl">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the following Jquery code:

```
    $(".nieuws_thumb_container").hover(function() {


    $(this).find('.nieuws_thumb_container_left').animate({
        width: "70%"
    }, 300 );
    $(this).find('.nieuws_thumb_container_right').animate({
        width: "30%"
    }, 300 );
});
```

However, I can't get it to run the animation. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: did you do it inside `$(document).ready`?

Comment: I did not. That does help. Thank you! Can I still mark the second answer as the correct one, as the code actually is correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

**HTML**:

```
<div class="nieuws_thumb_container">
  <div class="nieuws_content_left">
  </div>
  <div class="nieuws_content_right">
    <div class="pijl">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**JQuery**:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".nieuws_thumb_container").hover(function() {
        $(this).find('.nieuws_container_left').animate({
            width: "70%"
        }, 300 );
        $(this).find('.nieuws_container_right').animate({
            width: "30%"
        }, 300 );
    });
});
```

---

Change class **`nieuws_thumb_container_left`** & **`nieuws_container_right`** to **`nieuws_container_left`** & **`nieuws_container_right`**

Comment: Thank you. Although your code is correct, the missing $(document).ready did the trick!